# Can I use jQuery .each() in a comparison?

Tags: jquery, comparison, ecmascript-5

Quick question: Can I use jQuery .each() in a comparison?

For example if I have a form with multiple fields with an ID starting my "input":

```
if ($('[id^=input]').each().val() == '') {
// some functions here
}
```

(I want to make sure all fields are empty)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not going to work. `each()` doesn't work like that. Plain old Javascript however has an `every()` function that works on arrays. So you could do something like this instead:

```
if ($('[id^=input]').toArray().every(function(item){return item.value === ""})) {
       // Do stuff
     }
```

If you don't have to worry about older browsers you can make it a little easier on the eyes with:

```
if ($('[id^=input]').toArray().every(item => item.value === "")){ 
    //do stuff
    }
```